# ¿Como mostrar el nombre de la base de datos que se esta usando desde C#?

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un `Login` donde para abrirse hay que seleccionar el nombre de la `base de datos` y el `usuario` y la `contraseña` que se encuentran en una `tabla usuarios` pero necesito que al abrir la sesión y cerrarse el `login` cuando se abra el siguiente formulario `Menu` me muestre el nombre de la base de datos que estoy usando en un `label`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? Trabajo con `C#` y `Sql Server` en 3 Capas, Capa Datos,Capa Dominio y Capa Presentacion

```
 public class ConexionBasesDatos
{
 private string CadenConexionNueva;

        public string ConexionBasesD(string bd)
        {                        
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "DESKTOP-38N3PKP\\SQLEXPRESS";
            builder.InitialCatalog = bd;
            builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            return CadenConexionNueva = builder.ConnectionString;

        }
}
```

Comment: y donde esta el codigo que usas para conectarte?

Comment: @RamiroBarone ya edite

Comment: y guardar el valor de bd no sirve?

Comment: @gbianchi lo que necesito es que el valor que este el combobox (que es el nombre de la BD)se me guarde en una variable para poder mostrarla en un label y a su vez usar ese valor en los otros formularios, pero no se guarda la variable, entonces no se como obtener el nombre de la BD para pasarla como parametro en los demas formularios

Comment: supongo que esa clase publica vive durante todo tu programa? asi como el nombre de usuario y otras cosas? porque no guardas el nombre de la bd ahi?

Comment: @gbianchi porque dependiendo de el nombre que se le pase por el comobox va a abrir una BD

Comment: No es la que esta en initialcatalog?

Comment: @gbianchi no, es una variable que se le esta pasando y el nombre que entre ahi, es el initialcatalog, por eso quiero saber como agarrar ese nombre del combobox y ocultar el login mostrar le nombre en un label y pasarlo a los demas formularios

Comment: No usas como  ase de datos esa base de datos? Te conectas a ese catalogo y vas a otra? Tal vez no este entendiendo tu problema...

Comment: @gbianchi no se preocupe puede que no me explique bien,se lo dire de otra manera como puedo guardar el valor de una variable que esta en un formulario y pasarlo a otro? porque cuando cierro el formulario mi variable queda nula

Comment: Dentro de un objeto cualquiera. Como esa clase que mostras ahi.

Comment: Creo que tu problema no es que no sabes guardar una variable, seguramente cuando se la envias a un formulario nuevo, tiene dos opciones: Usar una clase Static y guardar el valor ahi, o cuando se la pasas por constructor, le adicionas una sobrecarga al constructor y le pasas la variable. Cuando crees el formulario, asegurate de usar ese constructor sobrecargado. Esas son opciones de muchas.

Comment: @RamiroBarone gracias ya lo resolvi, se destruia la variable antes de pasarla, estaba en una linea equivocada del codigo